# html anchor to download file from another server

Tags: html, download

As I have searched, making a download link is like

```
<a href="image_url.png" download>download</a>
```

But the image must be in project directory. How to download from another server?
For example if I want to download django logo the code is supposed to be:

```
<a href="https://www.djangoproject.com/s/img/logo-django.42234b631760.svg" download>download</a>
```

but that's not working (it opens and shows the image in the current tab instead of downloading), but any file in my own server is being downloaded easily. What is the best way to do that? tnx

Answer (score 0):

<s>You simply need to put name of the file (how it should be saved) in download. Like this:</s>

```
<a href="https://www.djangoproject.com/s/img/logo-django.42234b631760.svg" download="image.svg">download</a>
```

### Edit:

Actually I was wrong. You can find the answer [here](http://bl.ocks.org/curran/7cf9967028259ea032e8). If you want to download SVG in regular way, like any other file, you need to use JavaScript, not just plain HTML tags. Or you can download it as PNG, but as I assume: that's not the point.

Sorry for mistake.

Comment: it's not working. as I searched if you do not put the exact name, the image name would be the downloaded file name

Answer (score 0):

you put link in href on anchor tag:

```
<a href="https://www.djangoproject.com/s/img/logo-django.42234b631760.svg" download="img.svg">download</a>
```